# SQL Server login error while revalidating the login on the connection

Tags: sql-server, logins

Recently we started seeing the below error in our environment.

> Failed to open the database ‘XXXX’ configured in the login object while revalidating the login on the connection.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41820/connection-pools-being-reset-with-error-18056-severity-20-state-46-perfm).  Are you using connection pooling?  Please add the exact error messages from the SQL Server error log regarding this failure, and any other pertinent messages.

Comment: There is not a very good answer there, I am encouraging a new look at the older answers and potentially adding ones of your own.